# fetching data from mysql using Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to calculate the sum of prices sold between two specific dates. My query is okay but it isn't returning anything when i use in PHP. It works when i directly execute in database. 
Here is my code,

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
   var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
   try{

      // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }catch (e){

      // Internet Explorer Browsers
      try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e) {

         try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e){

            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
         }
      }
   }


   ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

      if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
         var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
         ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
      }
   }


   var startdate = document.getElementById('startdate').value;
   var enddate = document.getElementById('enddate').value;

   var queryString = "?startdate=" + startdate ;

   queryString +=  "&enddate=" + enddate;

   ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + queryString, true);
   ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>

<form name='myForm'>

   Start Date: <input type='date' id='startdate' /> <br />
   End Date: <input type='date' id='enddate' /> <br />

   <input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Query MySQL'/>

</form>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP Code

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "temp";

//Connect to MySQL Server
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

//Select Database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve data from Query String
$startdate = $_GET['startdate'];
$enddate = $_GET['enddate'];

//build query
$query = "SELECT SUM(price) FROM ajax_example WHERE daterec >= '$startdate'";
$query .= " AND daterec <= '$enddate'";

//Execute query
$qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


echo "Query: " . $query . "<br />";


?>
```

What am i doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: @AkramFares Its giving me a blank output!

Comment: use $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_result);
echo $row['price'];

Comment: If you execute `ajax-example.php` what does it show ?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions in this day and age. Look up **PDO** or **mysqli**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Satisj Rajak! you are right!

check [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

first, this function will be deprecated after PHP 5.5.0, try to dont use it.

second, to get the results you have "transform" the variable in an associative array using this example code:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['field_name'];
}
```

and if you use ajax, try to send a json format response.

hope my answer help you.

Comment: also check if the object ajaxRequest have a valid response or a html error.

Comment: helped me! And i got my program to work. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

In your button click handler, try returning false. My first instinct would be that your form is being submitted by that button and your AJAX request is never being completed.

```
<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction(); return false;' value='Query MySQL'/>
```

If that doesn't solve it, open up google chrome and the network debugging tools.  When you execute the AJAX request, check the request and response data.

In addition, you should optimize your JavaScript to be more effective.

Here is a snippet of JS which could be used in your situation:

```
  var get = function(path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', path);

      request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status == 200)
          resolve(request.response);
        else
          reject(Error(request.statusText));
      };

      request.onerror = function() {
        reject(Error(request.statusText));
      };

      request.send();
   });
 }

function fetchQueryResults() {
  get('/test.php').then(function(response) {
     var el = document.getElementById('results');
     el.innerHTML = response;
  }).catch(function(error) {
     // Something went wrong, handle the error here
  });
  return false;
}
```